# QR Code Got Expire ? with azure verifiable credential

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, decentralized-identity, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

I used "https://verifiedid.did.msidentity.com/v1.0/verifiableCredentials/createIssuanceRequest" api to generate my QR Code Response is

{
"requestId": "799f23ea-5241-45af-99ad-cf8e5018814e",
"url": "openid://vc?request_uri=https://verifiedid.did.msidentity.com/v1.0/12345678-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/verifiableCredentials/request/178319f7-20be-4945-80fb-7d52d47ae82e",
"expiry": 1622227690,
"qrCode": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KggoA"
}

but the issue is my QRcode get expire in 5 mins ?

any help on this.....

Comment: I strongly suspect that the QRCode is defined by the specification to be only valid for 5 minutes, but I cannot find any evidence to back that up...

Comment: i want that QR code to be lived for 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

The QR code is only valid for 5 minutes. If you want a QR code valid for longer, or even a static QR code, you need to do make the QR code point back to your app where you make the createIssuanceRequest at that point. The VC+B2C sample has a version of this, but for presentation. See the -link and -proxy methods https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials-dotnet/blob/main/3-asp-net-core-api-b2c/ApiVerifierController.cs

Comment: I have increased time 
   expiry = this place but my Microsoft authenticator app giving me error
"Error Code  Not Found Exception" Code "Not Found"